# Is it possible to set user password as MD5 hash in Centos?

Tags: centos, password

I want to set a user's password as MD5 hash value in Centos. I mean I don't know the password, but I have the hash MD5 value (md5sum). Is it possible?

Detailed explanation:
New password I want to set: 123
MD5 value of '123' is: dak37yd2o9d8m2ype9n8283up1m2
I want to run a command like this:

```
echo dak37yd2o9d8m2ype9n8283up1m2 | passwd --stdin -md5 myuser
```

So myuser can login with password 123

Comment: The hash you have given is not a valid md5 hash. MD5 outputs 128 bits, or 32 hexadecimal chars. You have supplied 29. The hash of the string `123` is `202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70`.

Comment: That was just a random value to explain my question, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: ah, I didn't realise

Answer (score 1):

A word of warning: As I am sure you have heard many a time, md5 is a broken hash function. Storing passwords hashed with it is only slightly better than plaintext.

After much researching, including trying things out on my own system, I was unable to find a way of using an existing hash that has not been salted. If you still have access to the password, or access to someone who knows it, you can use `chpasswd -e` to generate a salted hash.

If you have a salted hash, add the user to your system normally, if you haven't done so already. Pick any password you like, as we will overwrite it later.
Open the `/etc/shadow` file, and edit the line starting with the username of your user. Replace the second field (after the first colon, and before the second) with this:

```
$1$salt$hash
```

Where $salt$ is your salt, and $hash$ is the md5 hash in crypt base-64 format (https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/how-can-i-convert-a-sha-512-etc-shadow-hash-to-base64-4175477045/).

If the hash is unsalted, and you cannot gain access to the password through normal means, using something like `hashcat` to break it for you could be a viable option.

Comment: You can use `chpasswd -e` to set a password hash without editing `/etc/shadow` yourself manually. Purely looking at `man 3 crypt`, empty salt should be allowed (0 is "up to 16"), so `$1$$hash` might work. If it doesn't, filing a bug against glibc will likely lead to a documentation clarification that salt can't be empty.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I shall update my answer accordingly. I did try with an empty salt, but it gave me a different value that sha1sum, and I could not use it to log in.